# Behaviour of keep.rownames in R data.table::setDT()

Tags: r, data.table

I was just trying some code with data.table (`library(data.table)`) and noticed behaviour I found odd. Why does the first code here put rownames into the `rn` variable, while the second snippet doesn't? I am curious as to why this is happening. I would have thought the `copy()` and assign are done before the `setDT()` so it shouldn't have to be performed in two separate steps.

Keeps rownames:

```
dtcars <- copy(mtcars)
setDT(dtcars, keep.rownames=TRUE)
```

Does not keep rownames:

```
setDT(dtcars <- copy(mtcars), keep.rownames=TRUE)
```

I even tried with the assignment expressed as a function to make sure that was run first with

```
setDT(`<-`(dtcars, copy(mtcars)), keep.rownames=TRUE)
```

Compare this to the following where `x` is assigned before the call to `mean()` — I would expect my second snippet to behave like this but if the following behaved like my second snippet it would return `NA`.

```
mean(x <- c(rnorm(10, 0, 1), NA), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the `<-` operator is parsed to a function call (to the `` `<-` `` function) in R. What you don't seem to be aware of is that each function has a return value (even if it is just `NULL` and invisible).

The `` `<-` `` function has the side effect of assigning a value to a symbol. Its (invisible) return value is the value that is assigned. That's why you can do stuff like `y <- x <- 1`.

In your second and third example, `setDT` gets passed the return value of `` `<-` ``, which is a data.frame but not bound to a symbol. However, you want to pass it the symbol `dtcars`, which is what happens in your first example.

Since the return value is a shallow copy of the assigned data.frame, the assigned data.frame is also turned into a data.table. However, I don't understand C sufficiently to understand (from the source code) why adding the `rn` column to the return value doesn't also add it to the assigned data.table. I suggest [submitting an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).